# youtube channel on website

Tags: php, youtube

could someone give a hint or code of the channel which is information about the last 10 video clips, post it on the site. What I like about the effect on this page http://rezigiusz.pl/ .

Answer (score 0):

This is deprecated YouTube API 2.0, but you could use it. Not looked for the 3.0 API.

[YouTube API v2.0 - Video Feed Types](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos)